# What's the difference between a null modem cable and a gender changer?

Tags: rs232, db9

Please ignore this question. It doesn't address the problem I was trying to solve (XY problem) and my edits have been reverted. Because it has answers, I can't delete it. It should be closed as off-topic.

**TL;DR:** What's the difference between a null-modem cable and a gender-changer? Is a gender-changer a type of null-modem cable?

I have two devices, both with female DB/E-9 connectors, that I'd like to connect. I'm assuming they're electrically compatible, although I'll have to test this.

The devices in question are a [Sparkfun RS232 TTL shifter](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/449)<sup>1</sup> and an assumed passive [PS/2 (mini-DIN6) to RS232 adapter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Belkin-Female-Serial-RS232-Adaptor-x/dp/B006JQXTLQ) (not sure of the brand or pinout).

As far as I know, I can connect them with either a male-male gender changer or a null-modem cable. Given that there's more than one handshaking configuration for a null-modem cable (none, loop-back, partial or full), I'm not sure which is the best option. Should I use a gender-changer or create a null-modem cable?

The PS/2 pinout, for reference:

[image: PS/2 pinout, for reference]

---

1. Uses a MAX232 chip

Comment: hey, have you read the "Null Modem" Wikipedia article. *It comes with a wiring diagram* for a null modem cable; a gender changer only changes the gender of the plug you're using. Doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: I have read up on null modem cables. (Lammert Bies has an article/page on them.) I didn't see anything about gender changers, though. I generally avoid Wikipedia as a source for scientific topics; it's not exactly a reliable source.

Comment: not really a scientific topic.

Comment: Electronics: Based on electricity ... the chemistry and physics of electrons. Therefore, Science. No science, no technology.

Comment: No. This is technology. Not science; you're confusing *chemical engineering* with *chemistry*. Anyway, as a scientist: Wikipedia is just as fine a source if you simply check the sources that every single article cites. For technological things, Wikipedia is often not half bad.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an XY problem.  **The sparkfun level shifter is not compatible with a PS/2 interface** and no simple cable can change that. The Sparkfun level shifter is made for an opposing unidirectional interface, ie, a transmit and a receive and intended to be used with an asynchronous scheme. But the PS/2 interface is a synchronous scheme with a clock and a **bidirectional data line** which the Sparkfun device simply cannot handle.

Comment: Did you check out the [PS2Keyboard library](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/PS2Keyboard) on the Arduino site?

Comment: Your revised "multiple ways" end goal puts this back in the bad idea category.  If you have a serial keyboard (not these have been common in *decades*) then use that, if you have a PS/2 keyboard then *bit-bang* the PS/2 protocol on a digital pin.

Comment: @Transistor: Yes, I've skimmed through it. I clearly missed the part about serial connectors. In all my searching the Web (past two days; don't remember the exact pages), I've only seen how to make a DIN5 to mini-DIN6 adaptor and how to connect a mini-DIN6 to an arduino.

Comment: Don't search for the connector type, search for the protocol - PS/2.  You'll find the usual connector as part of the result.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Agreed. Judging by the effort/research-to-results ratio, it looks like I'm going down rabbit holes on an unwinnable race/wild goose chase for the sake of one connector.

Comment: That connector is not a hard problem *at all*.  It's what you'll find written up in just about any PS/2 keyboard with Arduino tutorial.  That's actually the easiest of your goals, it's all the others that will be hard.

Comment: I don't understand why the connector is not the hard problem, but it doesn't really matter in light of the fact that the other goals are hard. I'll just have to make do without it (or at least see how far I get).

Thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: @AgiHammerthief  The original question had received answers.  Don't edit the question so much that the answers to the original version no longer answer the new version.

Answer (score 1):

Gender changer changes the gender: male to female, female to male. The wires go straight, one on one, no dedicated wiring is implemented.

Null modem cable has connectors of the same gender an each side, but signals are swapped, paralleled,.. there is a dedicated wiring for that.

As for your application: It is hard to know, since PS/2 connector was used strictly for computer <-> device. You have CLK, DATA that you can't swap, so more likely you need a gender changer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there are three different things being discussed:

1. Gender changer. This just changes an IO port from male pins to female sockets, or female socket to male pins. A male-male or female-female can be used to connect two female cable ends together, or two male ends, or sometimes adapt a 9-pin to 25-pin.
2. Null modem and straight thru cables.  Typically with RS232 outputs, and say minimal connections on a 9-pin connector for the sake of this answer, only pins 2, 3, and 5 are connected. If one end has Rx on 2, Tx on 3, and Gnd on 5, and the other end has Tx on 2, Rx on 3, and Gnd on 5, then a straight cable can be used to connect Rx to Tx, Tx to Rx, and Gnd to Gnd.  If both ends have Rx on 2 and Tx on 3, then the cable needs to cross over those two.
3. TTL to RS232. www.nkcelectronics carries DB9 to 5V TTL output cards. One has a male DB9 connector, one has a female DB9 connector.  Check your cable ends to see which you need, and confirm whether the other end is expecting Rx/Tx on 2/3 or 3/2, and adjust your wiring to match.